# I would like to buy / I'm longing to buy

Tags: meaning-in-context

Are these sentences mean the same or the last one needs to use in another context? What phrase do you use usually in this case?

I know "long" like a verb means the following: to want something very much.

> **I would like to buy** that thing I've seen in a shop recently.
>
> **I'm longing to buy** that thing I've seen in a shop recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use ***long*** in such a casual sentence as yours. As a verb, *long* means:

> to feel a strong desire or craving especially for something not likely to be attained
>
> - they *long* for peace
> - *longing* to return home ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long))

As such, you wouldn't use *long* for trivial things, this is a deeper desire. Of course, depending on context, *that thing I've seen in a shop recently* could prove to be something "worthy" of longing, but the register of language used to describe it does not fit very well with *long*, which has a poetic touch to it.

So it would be more natural to say:

> I'd like to buy that thing I've seen in a shop recently.

(Note that the contraction ***'d*** fits better the register of the sentence. *I would like to* may come across as formal.)